# Please provide some direction about how much more focused this needs to be

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions, closed-questions

I've made several edits to this question trying to focus it for this site. But rather than guessing what is focused enough, could you please tell me how focused it needs to be? Even having some suggested wording would be helpful.

[Why actors change their accents long-term?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/118100/why-actors-change-their-accents-long-term)

Answer (score 4):

I'm one of the close voters, but I voted to close as opinion-based, not "needs more focus".

I believe that the question is more likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations.

Comment: Thank you! What about this answer on a similar question? https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/118138/96544

Answer (score -5):

The problem is that each actor may have a different reason for altering their accent and that the community believes there is not a common answer that would apply generally enough to answer the question when asked about actors generally rather than about specific actors. See: [Is the "needs more focus" close reason a catch-all?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4858/is-the-needs-more-focus-close-reason-a-catch-all#comment14367_4859)

Comment: Although, as the question-asker, I don't know on what basis the community believes there is not a general answer to the question. Having evidence about that would on it's own be valuable as an answer.

Comment: And wouldn't this have been a good answer to the question? https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/118138/96544

Answer (score -7):

The reason was that I was that the question requires statistical evidence to answer. I should have asked separate questions about individual actors.

It would not be appreciated to ask a different question for every single actor that one can find on YouTube, though.

Comment: I don't think asking a different question for every single actor you can find on YouTube would be much appreciated, though.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I was just proposing that "I should have asked separate questions about individual actors" as a potential answer to this question. The fact that it has been downvoted five times indicates that I was perhaps incorrect about that assertion.

Answer (score -8):

I'll post a competing answer to my own, so that votes can help me understand which is the right view.

I've been told that the real reason my question was closed was not about focus, [it was because the answer was obvious and the question wasn't interesting](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/118136/why-did-jennifer-lien-change-her-accent-away-from-her-chicago-accent#comment206584_118136)

Comment: I think you need to stop latching onto every little comment and taking it as the nonplusuntra word of god. You've gotten various responses to your questions so far and they sure can help understand what the community thinks about your question. But it seems like after every one of these you rush to meta and think *this* is the *one true* word of how the entire community feels about your question. Maybe take a step back, calm down, gather feedback, and try to craft an informed opinion out of it, rather than changing your mind (and your question) 180 degrees after every new comment.