# Is the "needs more focus" close reason a catch-all?

Tags: discussion

Is the close reason that says a question needs more focused always only used for questions that need more focus? Or is it sometimes used when no other close reason fits? Are some questions that are closed requiring more focus actually never going to be opened no matter how focused the question gets?

Answer (score 5):

*No*

I do not believe it is being used as a catch all close reason on this site.

Your secondary question about re-opening is also quite hard to definitively answer, because it will depend on the circumstances of each one.

There's no conspiracy against certain questions or people here, but yes, some questions may not attract enough re-open votes no matter how focused they get. I guess that really depends on how interesting they are as much as anything.

Comment: I believe it is being applied to your question because the answer will differ for each person who has done this, and people don't believe there is a common reason - i.e. the question is too broad.

Comment: Regarding your comment, I've proposed that as an answer to my question about my specific question, and the community does not seem to agree: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4860/96544